# ValueError: Labels are not in the input. For predicting examples without labels, please use the base model instead

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-classification

I am trying to predict label of an image but I am getting ValueError.
My code is

```
adv_model.fit(x={'feature': x_train, 'label': y_train}, batch_size=42, epochs=50)
img = Image.open('D:\Desktop Data\Minor Poject\Dataset\HAM10000_images_part_1\ISIC_0025306.jpg')
img1 = img.resize([56,42])
pix_val = list(img1.getdata())
pix_val = np.asarray(pix_val)
res = adv_model.predict({'feature': pix_val})
```

What should I do?

Comment: May you please share link to the model?

Comment: It is difficult to debug the issue, can you provide complete code and error stacktrace to investigate the issue. Thanks!